# three ways to achieve an H264 file

Tags: c, ffmpeg

here I have three ways to get an H264 file, like all forensic scientists, I am very curious about the differences between them:

1.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 video.h264
```

2.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vcodec copy -an -f h264 video.h264
```

3. Using the example "demuxing_decoding.c" provided on the ffmpeg official website:
http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/demuxing_decoding_8c-example.html

Obviously, the first one does the transformation, and the second one does the demuxing. They render different H264 files which however have similar file sizes(in my case, it's about say 24 MB). Suprisingly, the third one, which is also supposed to do the demuxing job, renders an H264 file with 8.4 GB! Why?

What I wondered is really, how the interiors of these three methods work?(The third one is already in source code, therefore it's quite easy to have an insight) What about the first two commands? What APIs are called when executing these two commands and how those APIs are called(namely, in what kind of sequences they are called) and things like that. 
One thing that is also important to me is, i have no idea how I can trace the execution routines of ffmpeg command lines. I want to see what's going on behind ffmpeg commands in source code version. Is it possible?

I appreciate any comment.

Comment: Well I've inserted some printf() functions (eg. printf("test1\n"), printf("test2\n") and so on) into ffmpeg libraries hoping it would reveal the execution routines of ffmpeg command line. It did help to trace the execution. But it turned out to be not very effective(or efficient): on the one hand, one has to firstly guess which APIs could be executed bebfore he can insert printfs. This kind of guess isn't accurate nor sufficient to cover all routines. On the other hand, the whole lib would have to be recompiled, which is somehow too trivial...

Comment: If you look at the source code of the third method, it is writing the raw decoded video and audio frames to disk, thus explaining the huge, uncompressed size.

Comment: @Scott Aha..I see your point! With the first two methods, data was somehow recompressed! But It would be nice to be capable to see the inside of those two commands, namely, how libraries are called when executing them...